# Flink 1.13.2 not updates metrics in near-real-time when connected to kafka sources/sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm creating a process to handle millions of records with apache flink to support logistics data pipelines. I'm moving from kinesis sources/sink to kafka sources/sink.

However, in the flink dashboard, the job metrics are not being updated in the near-real-time. Do you know what can be wrong with the job/version?

Btw, when job is closed, then it can show all metrics... but not in near-real-time...

Job non-updating metrics picture

[image: 1]

Comment: Does the job actually process anything?

Comment: yes. job is processing correctly. But no metrics update during the process. Even the watermark value is not updated during data processing...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after cleanup conflict dependencies on "Kafka-clients" lib.

So, in my case, using also some avro & cloudevents libs with higher Kafka-clients version. Then, just need to exclude Kafka-clients from these libs and prefer flink Kafka-clients version. And this solved the issue.